# Converting String to Array of BigInteger in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a BigInteger or a String variable containing no.s into a BigInteger Array.
How can i do this. please reply.
for eg.

```
BigInteger = 278490638904984
BigInteger Array = [2,7,8,4,9,0,6,3,8,9,0,4,9,8,4]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "278490638904984";
    BigInteger[] big = new BigInteger[s.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        big[i] = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(big));
}
```

Output:

```
[2, 7, 8, 4, 9, 0, 6, 3, 8, 9, 0, 4, 9, 8, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this:

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(myString);
```

You then will have to assign that to a position in an array of BigIntegers.

Note, if your string cannot be converted, it will throw a NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 1):

For which purpose? It's a little bit strange...

```
BigInteger   bi = new BigInteger( "278490638904984" );
String       s  = bi.toString();
int          len = s.length();
BigInteger[] digits = new BigInteger[len];
for( int i = 0; i < len; ++i ) {
   digits[i] = BigInteger.valueOf( s.charAt(i)-'0' );
}
```

Comment: charAt(i) - '0' is equal to Character.toNumericValue()

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert BigInteger value toString(), then get length of the String like str.length() and create an array of desired size.

After this you can fill the array with values:

```
array[i] = new BigInteger(str.substring(i, i+1));
```

It's not brilliant solution, but should do the job.